# Redirect request to any server to a mock server

Tags: nginx, mocking, reverse-proxy

I have an application which makes HTTP requests to different web servers(i.e. www.server1.com/path1, www.server2.com/path2 and many more) on internet. I am trying to create a mock server which will fake all of these server. Now, the problem is that when my application makes a request it make a request to server1 or server2 or any of the other servers.

How do I redirect all of this request to my mock server so that I can read these request and return a mock response back to my application?

I tried searching about reverse-proxy and nginx but could to find answer to my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do this locally during development, I suggest you try setting up some [AutoResponder rules](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/AutoResponder) in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Basically Fiddler acts as a proxy where you can set up regex rules for which url patterns you want redirected somewhere else. I'm using this method all the time and it works really well. Also it doesn't require any changes to your code.

Comment: not just locally, I want to use this feature LAN wide/intranet-wide/VPN-wide/company-wide.
Let me read about AutoResponder and get back if it suit my requirements.